# android call log like design

Tags: android, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a design for a list that looks like (and mostly behaves like) the call log, like shown here:
[ImageHost.org http://i.imagehost.org/0374/android_consistency.jpg](http://i.imagehost.org/0374/android_consistency.jpg)

I don't need all the design, but what I'm trying to achieve is the two-columned design with the splitter in-between, and the behavior that if I click on the main item (the left part) one thing happens (in this case, you open some details about the call), and if you press the outer right part something else happens (you call the contact).

I'm pretty new to android, but I've managed to do most of the designs I wanted so far, so I don't need the entire layout for this one, only the part that does the splitting and the splitter. And if possible it would be nice to know how to map the clicks appropriately, though I think I might be able to find that out by my self.

Comment: @Alexandr, did you built the layout like the CallLog? What code for the Activity did you used? The xml code worked fine? How you did that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read the android's source code.
Check [this repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary).

You have the Call log's source code there.

Comment: Do you happen to know where I can find the call log? I can't find it :-S.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I found it: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=res/layout-finger/recent_calls_list_item.xml;h=5439ff33f63413e31c4b792227387ef5db6eff46;hb=543e96aa39ab408aaaf83a2de364a01ca07f3689